# Change meteor accounts-google redirect uri

Tags: redirect, meteor, oauth, uri

I have a meteor app with the accounts-ui and accounts-google packages installed. However, when I set up the client id and secret, the app set the redirect uri as localhost. So whenever I access my app from a remote location, it redirects me to localhost, but I'm remote, so it just tells me it can't connect to localhost. Is there anyway to tell meteor that when I'm connecting local, the redirect uri is localhost, and when i'm connecting remote, the redirect uri is the remote location? Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply set the `ROOT_URL` environment variable to your IP address (at least while you need to create accounts)?

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I had no idea I could set that variable.